# html2pdf covert html to pdf from url

Tags: php, html2pdf

Trying to generate PDFs with html2pdf. I want to generate using a URL.

The code I have generates a PDF, but the PDF is blank which, I assume, means not HTML is being pulled from the specified url.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf.class.php');
$url = 'http://example.com/survey/exportpdf.php?id=6';
try
{
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
    //$html2pdf->setModeDebug();

    $html2pdf->getHtmlFromPage($url);

    $html2pdf->Output($id.'.pdf','D');
}
catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}
```

Is anyone familiar with html2pdf? I've gone through the docs and the examples, but I can't find any reference to this method. I've found the definition here, but it doesn't tell much.

Comment: Have you tried using `header('Content-type: application/pdf');`

Comment: yes i have tried with including header also... but no luck..

Comment: what is the output if you directly call the url inside of your browser ? 

If it does show you the correct HTML did you try to fetch it with file_get_contents() and put the fetched HTML into html2pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to get the url html :

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
```

Comment: It worked fine, I used the same for multilingual Japanese text. It works for multilingual too, but fine name is not japanese. If I pass Japanese test fro filename, it gives blank filename. If possible suggest me help here.